# Hibernate write conflicts in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am using Grails 1.3.7 with MySQL. My application server records search results of queries users run. The schema (simplified) consists of

```
class Query {
    String query
    String user
}

class Document {
    String externalId
    String title
}

class Posting {
    Query query
    Document document
    int rank
}
```

Whenever a user runs a query that retrieves a document for the first time, I create a new instance; otherwise, I reuse an existing instance when creating the corresponding `Posting` instances.  Only one instance of  `Document` should exist for a given `externalId`, but multiple `Posting` instances can point to it.

More than one user can run queries that retrieve the same documents, but that creates a concurrency issue. If two users retrieve the same document for the first time at approximately the same time, the second attempt to create a `Document` will fail with a unique constraint violation on `externalId`. This is good. The bad thing, is that the newly-created `Posting` instance associated with the duplicate `Document` will also get rolled back. This is not good, as by the point it's difficult to figure out how to retry the save.

The solution I came up with is to create the `Document` by using a synchronized method that calls `save(flush: true)`, and if that fails, re-reads the document from the database. The resulting document (whether saved or re-read) is then used to populate the `Posting` instance. This solution works, but is too slow to process the results my users retrieve. If I get rid of the `flush: true` parameter, performance improves, but then I am not guaranteed that `Document` and `Posting` instances will get created properly.

What's the right way to implement this kind of update?

*CLARIFICATION*

The queries I am running return 100 matches at a time, which means I am creating 0-100 `Document` instances and 100 `Posting` instances per user request.

Comment: [This](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/11/12/the-false-optimism-of-gorm-and-hibernate/) is a good read in the mean time we find a liable solution for your use case. :)

Comment: That's an informative post. One thing he doesn't discuss is why Hibernate doesn't have a clean "update on duplicate" interface. That could punt some of these issues to the DB. It would certainly help me: I could lose the foreign key constraint between `Posting` and `Document` and everything could be saved in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding the question fully, so this might sound a little naive. Couldn't you solve this with [optimistic locking](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking) ?

In your catch block, assuming the second user is the one coming to the party late, couldn't you then pull the lastest version of the document and assign to the second user's Posting.

```
try {
    def posting = .... 
    posting.save(flush: true)
}
catch (org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
    def doc = Document.findByExternalId(posting.document.externalId)
    posting.document = doc
    posting.save(flush: true)
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but the performance problem comes from two sources: 1. lots of flushes to the database (I am getting approx 100 results per query), 2. waiting for all of these flushes to complete before returning some JSON to the client. If I could write all the stuff to the database once (rather than 100 times), and could do that *after* the response is written to the client, the overall performance would be much better.

Comment: I see - so you're saving quite a large number of Posting/Document and some of them may fail. It's a good question - I'm curious to see what SO community comes up with.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky If the persistence happens in one hibernate `session`then you can use `flush: true` on the last save instead of flushing it on each save, hibernate will take care of all saves at once.

Comment: The conflicts occur when two different users retrieve the same document at about the same time. So the issue is that there are multiple hibernate sessions, which is why a write of a `Document` might fail. At the real problem with that is that the `Posting` related to the document the also fails to save.